# Document access control in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm designing my first project with ElasticSearch. The system will hold around 100,000,000 documents of which 95% are publicly accessible, but 5% are visible only to one or more users. Users will query their private data along with the public data. What would be the preferred method of restricting access to the private data without impacting performance of the public data search? I imagine that adding user IDs to all private documents and then excluding these documents in all public searches is not going to help performance? Should I perhaps use multiple indexes (or types) and restrict public searches to the public index?

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely put the 5M private documents in a separate index and then use aliases to include only the public index(es) (`public` alias) or both the private and public indexes (`all` alias) in the search.

You can also add a `private` boolean field (true/false) to your documents (all stored in the same index), but then you run the risk of leaking information if for some reason you forget to include a `term` query on that field in one or more of your queries + all aggregations you might end up doing.